# Check if QAction is initialized

Tags: qt, qt5

I have in my header file the definition:

```
QAction actionPlay;
```

In my cpp file I have a function:

```
myFunc()
{
    actionPlay = new QAction();
}
```

I want to make a change in my UI only the first time I enter the function myFunc().

I thought about checking if actionPlay has been initialized or not (if we have already called the line `actionPlay = new QAction();` )

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
actionPlay = new QAction()
```

is attempting to assign a pointer to a non pointer variable declared in

```
QAction actionPlay
```

so wont works as is.

If you changed the code to:

```
QAction * actionPlay = 0;
```

It would work, and you could then check if it was initialized:

```
if(!actionPlay) actionPlay = new QAction();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to init action for every object:

```
QACtion *actionPay = nullptr; // *.h file
if(!actionPay) { actionPay = new QAction(); ..... } // *.cpp file
```

or don't use pointer

```
if(!actionPay.isEnabled()) { ... enable actionPay ...} // *.cpp file
```

if you want do one action:

```
//in your function *.cpp file
static bool once = true;
if(once) { 
    once = false;
     ... some code executed in the first call ... 
}
```